Linker errors building server app with gRPC in C++
I'm starting a new C++ project using gRPC. I have never used gRPC in a C++ project before and am generally following the instructions from the gRPC Quick Start Guide.
After the installation, there are some pkg-config directories, so I decided that would be the best way to link everything together. This is also my first time using pkg-config.
To test whether I have my PATH set up correctly, I ran the following.
$ which grpc_cpp_plugin
/home/me/devel/projects/cpp/myapp/grpc/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin

That seemed to work correctly. So I tested the pkg-config stuff.
$ pkg-config --cflags grpc
-DCARES_STATICLIB -pthread -DNOMINMAX -I@includedir@ -I/home/me/devel/projects/cpp/myapp/grpc/include

$ pkg-config --libs grpc
-L/home/me/devel/projects/cpp/myapp/grpc/lib -lgrpc -labsl_statusor -lgpr -labsl_log_internal_check_op -labsl_flags_internal -labsl_flags_reflection -labsl_flags_private_handle_accessor -labsl_flags_commandlineflag -labsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal -labsl_flags_config -labsl_flags_program_name -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_flags_marshalling -labsl_log_internal_conditions -labsl_log_internal_message -labsl_examine_stack -labsl_log_internal_format -labsl_log_internal_proto -labsl_log_internal_nullguard -labsl_log_internal_log_sink_set -labsl_log_internal_globals -labsl_log_sink -labsl_log_entry -labsl_log_globals -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_low_level_hash -labsl_vlog_config_internal -labsl_log_internal_fnmatch -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal -labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle -labsl_crc_cord_state -labsl_crc32c -labsl_crc_internal -labsl_crc_cpu_detect -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_strerror -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_kernel_timeout_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_string_view -labsl_base -lrt -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity

That also appeared to work as expected.
My makefile (using GNU make, not cmake) looks like this.
COMPILE_FLAGS = -std=c++20 -c -Wall $(shell pkg-config --cflags grpc)
LINK_FLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs grpc)

SERVER_OBJECT_FILES = server.o myapp.pb.o myapp.grpc.pb.o

# link the program
release : myapp.pb.o myapp.grpc.pb.o $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES)
#   g++ -o myapp-server $(LINK_FLAGS) $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES)
    g++ -o myapp-server $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES) $(LINK_FLAGS)

server.o : server.cpp
    g++ $(COMPILE_FLAGS) -o server.o server.cpp

myapp.pb.o : protos/myapp.pb.cc
    g++ $(COMPILE_FLAGS) -o myapp.pb.o protos/myapp.pb.cc

myapp.grpc.pb.o : protos/myapp.grpc.pb.cc
    g++ $(COMPILE_FLAGS) -o myapp.grpc.pb.o protos/myapp.grpc.pb.cc

It compiles, but it does not link.
You'll notice that I have 2 linker commands that reverse the order of LINK_FLAGS and SERVER_OBJECT_FILES. One is commented out and the other is not. There was a suggestion that the order of the flags in the linker command was causing this problem, so I ran it both ways. Both commands produce hundreds of linker errors.
This is approximately the first 12 errors from the first linker command.
g++ -o myapp-server -L/home/me/devel/projects/cpp/myapp/grpc/lib -lgrpc -labsl_statusor -lgpr -labsl_log_internal_check_op -labsl_flags_internal -labsl_flags_reflection -labsl_flags_private_handle_accessor -labsl_flags_commandlineflag -labsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal -labsl_flags_config -labsl_flags_program_name -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_flags_marshalling -labsl_log_internal_conditions -labsl_log_internal_message -labsl_examine_stack -labsl_log_internal_format -labsl_log_internal_proto -labsl_log_internal_nullguard -labsl_log_internal_log_sink_set -labsl_log_internal_globals -labsl_log_sink -labsl_log_entry -labsl_log_globals -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_low_level_hash -labsl_vlog_config_internal -labsl_log_internal_fnmatch -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal -labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle -labsl_crc_cord_state -labsl_crc32c -labsl_crc_internal -labsl_crc_cpu_detect -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_strerror -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_kernel_timeout_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_string_view -labsl_base -lrt -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity server.o myapp.pb.o myapp.grpc.pb.o
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.grpc.pb.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN4grpc6Status2OKE' in read-only section `.text._ZN4grpc18GenericDeserializeINS_17ProtoBufferReaderEN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteEEENS_6StatusEPNS_10ByteBufferEPS4_[_ZN4grpc18GenericDeserializeINS_17ProtoBufferReaderEN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteEEENS_6StatusEPNS_10ByteBufferEPS4_]'
/usr/bin/ld: server.o: in function `MessagesServiceImpl::GetMessage(grpc::ServerContext*, myapp::MessageRequest const*, myapp::MessageResponse*)':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN19MessagesServiceImpl10GetMessageEPN4grpc13ServerContextEPKN5myapp14MessageRequestEPNS3_15MessageResponseE[_ZN19MessagesServiceImpl10GetMessageEPN4grpc13ServerContextEPKN5myapp14MessageRequestEPNS3_15MessageResponseE]+0x34): undefined reference to `grpc::Status::OK'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::TcParser::ParseLoop(google::protobuf::MessageLite*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*, google::protobuf::internal::TcParseTableBase const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::ByteSizeLong() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::MaybeComputeUnknownFieldsSize(unsigned long, google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::MergeImpl(google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x39b): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20240116::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x3c5): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20240116::log_internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::GetMetadata() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x4fd): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const* (*)(), absl::lts_20240116::once_flag*, google::protobuf::Metadata const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x6b9): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::TcParser::ParseLoop(google::protobuf::MessageLite*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*, google::protobuf::internal::TcParseTableBase const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x7b1): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x7d2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'

And this is approximately the first 12 errors from the second linker command.
g++ -o myapp-server server.o myapp.pb.o myapp.grpc.pb.o -L/home/me/devel/projects/cpp/myapp/grpc/lib -lgrpc -labsl_statusor -lgpr -labsl_log_internal_check_op -labsl_flags_internal -labsl_flags_reflection -labsl_flags_private_handle_accessor -labsl_flags_commandlineflag -labsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal -labsl_flags_config -labsl_flags_program_name -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_flags_marshalling -labsl_log_internal_conditions -labsl_log_internal_message -labsl_examine_stack -labsl_log_internal_format -labsl_log_internal_proto -labsl_log_internal_nullguard -labsl_log_internal_log_sink_set -labsl_log_internal_globals -labsl_log_sink -labsl_log_entry -labsl_log_globals -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_low_level_hash -labsl_vlog_config_internal -labsl_log_internal_fnmatch -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal -labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle -labsl_crc_cord_state -labsl_crc32c -labsl_crc_internal -labsl_crc_cpu_detect -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_strerror -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_kernel_timeout_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_string_view -labsl_base -lrt -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: warning: relocation against `_ZTVN6google8protobuf7MessageE' in read-only section `.text._ZN6google8protobuf7MessageC2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf7MessageC5Ev]'
/usr/bin/ld: server.o: in function `MessagesServiceImpl::GetMessage(grpc::ServerContext*, myapp::MessageRequest const*, myapp::MessageResponse*)':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN19MessagesServiceImpl10GetMessageEPN4grpc13ServerContextEPKN5myapp14MessageRequestEPNS3_15MessageResponseE[_ZN19MessagesServiceImpl10GetMessageEPN4grpc13ServerContextEPKN5myapp14MessageRequestEPNS3_15MessageResponseE]+0x34): undefined reference to `grpc::Status::OK'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::TcParser::ParseLoop(google::protobuf::MessageLite*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*, google::protobuf::internal::TcParseTableBase const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::ByteSizeLong() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::MaybeComputeUnknownFieldsSize(unsigned long, google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageRequest::GetMetadata() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x4fd): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const* (*)(), absl::lts_20240116::once_flag*, google::protobuf::Metadata const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::_InternalParse(char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*)':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x6b9): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::TcParser::ParseLoop(google::protobuf::MessageLite*, char const*, google::protobuf::internal::ParseContext*, google::protobuf::internal::TcParseTableBase const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::_InternalSerialize(unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*) const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x7b1): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::default_instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x7d2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::InternalSerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const&, unsigned char*, google::protobuf::io::EpsCopyOutputStream*)'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::ByteSizeLong() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0x86e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::MaybeComputeUnknownFieldsSize(unsigned long, google::protobuf::internal::CachedSize*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: myapp.pb.o: in function `myapp::MessageResponse::GetMetadata() const':
myapp.pb.cc:(.text+0xa9b): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const* (*)(), absl::lts_20240116::once_flag*, google::protobuf::Metadata const&)'

In the output from the two linker commands above, the complete expanded, invoked g++ command is the first line.
So simply reversing the order of the flags does not solve the problem. Most of the linker errors look very similar between the two commands. I haven't compared all of them because they both produce hundreds of errors, but it seems like most of the errors are the same but in a different order.
There has to be a way to get this to link. Fixing linker errors usually requires minor changes to the build process.
Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Swap the occurrence order of $(LINK_FLAGS) and $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES)

@3CxEZiVlQ I tried g++ $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES) -o myapp-server $(LINK_FLAGS) and g++ -o myapp-server $(SERVER_OBJECT_FILES) $(LINK_FLAGS) but both of them gave me the same linker errors I was getting before.

The same linker errors are impossible. Show the complete invoked g++ command.
